# I want to check whether a string contains specific characters repeated more than thrice

Tags: java, regex, string

For example, if I have a string containing 'A' or 'B' or 'C' more than three times in a row, that string is invalid:

```
PPAAAFAL - Valid , 
AAABBBCC- valid , 
NABCCCC - invalid , 
AAAAAAAA- invalid ... etc.
```

I know that I can check for repetition like `A{0,3}` but how to check for all characters in one RegEx?
The string can start and end with any character.

Comment: Why does it have to be a regex? Write a simple method to check this.

Comment: I thought using regex would be faster and easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `string.matches`. Below regex should match only invalid strings. That is, the string having 4 or more `A`'s or `B`'s or `C`'s.

```
if (string.matches(".*([ABC])\\1{3,}.*")) {
    System.out.println("Invalid");
} else {
    System.out.println("Valid");
}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tK4nR9/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works. Can you please let me know what should I read to understand this and create more such regex?

Comment: @SanketPimple http://www.regular-expressions.info/ seems like a good site for learning regex.